# Display my filled array values into listbox and optionally delete them

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, null, listbox

Ok, so with the help of awesome guys here on Stackoverflow I have created my array like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form    
{
    string[] Brands = new string[10];
    int brandNo;}

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       Brands[0] = "Yamaha"; //ok
       Brands[1] = "Suzuki"; //ok
       Brands[2] = "Harley"; //ok
       Brands[3] = "Kawasaki"; //ok
       brandNo = 4;
    }

    private void buttonAddbrand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (brandNo >= 10)
          return; //cannot add more brand

       Brands[brandNo++] = textBoxMerk.Text;
       var Merk = Brands
       listBoxMotoren.Items.Clear();

       listBoxMotoren.Items.AddRange(Merk);
```

With this code I want to display the filled values of the array in my listbox. But I get the following error:

> value can not be null.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need separate array to hold brands? Button handler can be as simple as `listBoxMotoren.Items.Add(textBoxMerk.Text);`. And to the question: you have syntax error in given code (missing `;` and `}`), make sure you show us **real code** which contains mistake, provide **complete** error message and specify all details like at which line it occurs, was it a compile- or run-time, etc.

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry, didn't copy it right. Syntax errors are gone. I get this error message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34741882/edit) your question to provide relevant details. And you forgot to tell at which line error occurs (add comment `// error here`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, be careful of where you put your curly bracket as to ensure that the code can be compiled.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form    
{
    string[] Brands = new string[10];
    int brandNo;} //<- off-placed
```

Secondly, since you start with making the array as your `DataSource` (and not using `Items.Add` or `Items.AddRange` to your `listBoxMotoren`, it may be consistent if you doing so on addition or removal of your item in the `listBoxMotoren`.

```
private void buttonAddbrand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (brandNo >= 10)
        return; //cannot add more brand

    Brands[brandNo++] = textBoxMerk.Text;
    listBoxMotoren.DataSource = null; //the cheapest and dirtiest trick to do this
    listBoxMotoren.DataSource = Brands; //Maintaining the style, use `DataSource` to accommodate new data
}
```

Lastly, if you want to remove the brand item at will, you might need another `Control` in your `Form1` as an input for which item in the brand you want to get optionally delete. But beware that this may "destroy" the sequence of your items and thus you may need to "re-sequencing" your item.

Now, suppose you use `NumericUpDown` to delete and trigger the deletion using `buttonDeletebrand` then you should do something like this

```
private void buttonDeletebrand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int indexToDelete = (int)numericUpDownMotorenNumberDeleted.Value; //note the casting to (int)
    if (indexToDelete < 0 || indexToDelete >= brandNo || brandNo <= 0) //can only delete index no [0] to [brandNo-1], and if the brand no > 0
        return; //invalid index
    for (int i = indexToDelete; i < brandNo - 1; ++i)
        Brands[indexToDelete] = Brands[indexToDelete + 1]; //resequencing
    Brands[brandNo - 1] = string.Empty; //removes the last element after resequencing
    listBoxMotoren.DataSource = null; //remember the cheapest and dirtiest trick?
    listBoxMotoren.DataSource = Brands;
    --brandNo; //reduce the brandNo by 1
}
```

In total, you need all of them combined:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    string[] Brands = new string[10];
    int brandNo;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Brands[0] = "Yamaha";
        Brands[1] = "Suzuki";
        Brands[2] = "Harley";
        Brands[3] = "Kawasaki";
        brandNo = 4;
        listBoxMotoren.DataSource = Brands;
    }

    private void buttonAddbrand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (brandNo >= 10)
            return;

        Brands[brandNo++] = textBoxMerk.Text;
        listBoxMotoren.DataSource = null;
        listBoxMotoren.DataSource = Brands;
    }

    private void buttonDeletebrand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int indexToDelete = (int)numericUpDownMotorenNumberDeleted.Value;
        if (indexToDelete < 0 || indexToDelete >= brandNo || brandNo <= 0)
            return;
        for (int i = indexToDelete; i < brandNo - 1; ++i)
            Brands[indexToDelete] = Brands[indexToDelete + 1];
        Brands[brandNo - 1] = string.Empty;
        listBoxMotoren.DataSource = null;
        listBoxMotoren.DataSource = Brands;
        --brandNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you once again. But unfortunately it doesn't work. When I click the Addbrand button it doesn't crash or something, but just doesn't display anything into the listbox. The strange part is that I have exactly the same code as you have.

Comment: @Needsomehelp are you serious? but the Addbrand is identical with what you have previously, no? Please check again. And using debugger if possible

Comment: `private void buttonAddbrand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (brandNo >= 10)
        return; //cannot add more brand

    Brands[brandNo++] = textBoxMerk.Text;
    listBoxMotoren.DataSource = null; //the cheapest and dirtiest trick to do this
    listBoxMotoren.DataSource = Brands; //Maintaining the style, use `DataSource` to accommodate new data
}` if your brandNo does not exceed 10, this must put something

Comment: I am lost. I copied your code. Program runs fine. No problems compiling. But when I click the add buttong: nothing shows up on the listbox =(

Comment: May be it is because you `copied` my code... It is to be `remade` (for your better understanding too!), not `copied`... Do you handle your `buttonAddbrand_Click` event in your designer?

Comment: Yeah at first I jsut remade your code. But when it didn't worked, I double checked. When this also failed, I just copied your code. Even then the listbox doesn't show a thing. What do you mean exactly with "handle btn event in your designer"

Comment: Did you "double click" your `buttonAddbrand` in the designer? If you don't then you cannot event enter the even handler `buttonAddbrand_Click`. I mean, each of your `control` (such as `buttonAddbrand`) in the designer, in order for it to enter the event handler (such as `buttonAddbrand_Click`) must have that event handler added to the control. Typically this is done automatically by visual studio when you "double click" on the control in the designer view. But if you copy paste the code, this step is skipped.

Comment: Oh like that, yes I did. But if I didn't, I would get a error if i'm correct.

Comment: You got to make sure that the name of the event handler in you `class.cs` file is identical to what is in the `class.designer.cs` file then the event will fire. Without which, the reason why you did not add anything is not because there is anything wrong with the program, but because the `button` `click` event is not handled at all. Check it out!

Comment: I'm comparing the form1.cs and the form1.designer.cs right now. Name is exactly the same!

Comment: Do you have this line `this.buttonAddbrand.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAddbrand_Click);` in your `designer.cs`?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'm 100% sure. Looking at it right now.

Comment: Ok, and if you put break point inside the `buttonAddbrand_Click` event handler, and then you run the program and click `buttonAddbrand`, does your program really go inside the `buttonAddbrand_Click` event handler?

Comment: In that case please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770189/bind-listdouble-to-winforms-listbox/34770430#34770430 you may need to use `BindingList`

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure this code do not even compile....

```
   int brandNo;} <- "}" ???

   var Merk = Brands <- ";" missing and (var Merk) not needed
```

locking at this code i guess the problem is in
check

```
if (listBoxMotoren != null && listBoxMotoren.Items.Any()) 
       listBoxMotoren.Items.Clear();
```

and of cource

```
if (listBoxMotoren != null && Brands  != null)
   listBoxMotoren.Items.AddRange(Brands);
```

if listboxMotoren is null the form is not initialized yet as long listBoxMotoren is a form Control

Answer (score 1):

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
   string[] Brands = new string[10];
     int brandNo;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Brands[0] = "Yamaha"; //ok
        Brands[1] = "Suzuki"; //ok
        Brands[2] = "Harley"; //ok
        Brands[3] = "Kawasaki"; //ok
        brandNo = 4;
        listBoxMotoren.DataSource=Brands;//asssiign the current list to //listbox
    }

    private void buttonAddbrand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (brandNo >= 10)
      return; //cannot add more brand

   Brands[brandNo++] = textBoxMerk.Text;

   listBoxMotoren.DataSource = null; //make the list empty
   listBoxMotoren.DataSource = Brands;// assgin it new list
    }
```