# Bind List<Double> to WinForms-Listbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I have an small (probably dumb) issue with databinding. I try to bind a List

```
List<double> _measuredValues = new List<double>();
```

to a winforms ListBox.

In Form_Load I set:

```
lstMeasuredValues.DataSource = _measuredValues;
```

When I update the values, nothing appears?!

```
_measuredValues.Add(numBuffer);
```

One thing I thought about is a data type issue. But how do I change the type just to change it into a string?

```
lstMeasuredValues.DataSource = _measuredValues.ToString().ToList();
```

Another reason might be that the upper line of code is within another thread. But I think this should not be the problem.

How can I bind this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I update the values, nothing appears?!
>
> _measuredValues.Add(numBuffer);

In order to allow UI to reflect the data source modifications, the data source must provide some sort of a change notification. WinForms list data binding infrastructure uses [ListChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.listchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of the  [IBindingList Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx). There is a standard provided [BindingList<T> class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be used instead of `List<T>` to get the desired behavior. All you need is changing this line

```
List<double> _measuredValues = new List<double>();
```

to

```
BindingList<double> _measuredValues = new BindingList<double>();
```

> Another reason might be that the upper line of code is within another thread. But I think this should not be the problem.

That's not good. You **must** make sure you don't do that because `ListChanged` event is expected to be raised on the UI thread.

Comment: Well, you're absolutely right. Using the BindigList only works if the new value is added when the UI thread is invoked. So thank's a lot. I thought about thread-safe control calls but missed the fact, that events will stay within the caller thread. Now It works fine with the BindingList.

Answer (score 3):

The better way is to clear the items and assign the DataSource again:

```
lstMeasuredValues.Items.Clear()// clear all items
lstMeasuredValues.DataSource = _measuredValues;
```

Or even you can define your own refresh function and call like the following:

```
public void RefreshList()
 {
   lstMeasuredValues.Items.Clear()// clear all items
   lstMeasuredValues.DataSource = _measuredValues;
 }
```

And call them when ever you need to refresh the list:

```
_measuredValues.Add(numBuffer);
RefreshList();
// Add more values 
RefreshList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the common `List` isn't the right choice for data binding. You should use [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-USlibrary/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to keep updated the ListBox.

Try using it this way:

```
BindingList<double> bindList = new BindingList<double>(_measuredValues);
lstMeasuredValues.DataSource = bindList;
```

Keep in mind that when you add a new item in _measuredValues you have to manually refresh the binding, as far as I now, like this:

```
bindList.ResetBindings();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `BindingList<double>` as DataSource of your Listbox

```
List<double> _measuredValues = new List<double>();
BindingList<double> bindList = new BindingList<double>(_measuredValues);
lstMeasuredValues.DataSource = bindList;
```

Now everytime you need to add an element use the bindList variable and your listbox will update automatically as well as your `_measuredValues` list

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way to do it is by putting:

```
lstMeasuredValues.DataSource = null; //the cheapest, trickiest, but the most important line
lstMeasuredValues.DataSource = _measuredValues;
```

Whenever your `_measuredValues` element is updated

Comment: It basically is the same solution like everyone here has recommended but it's the shortest :)

Comment: @AllDayPiano true, I like it the most too. =) because it is the simplest in my opinion.

Comment: I used this solution in the past, but I'm afraid of unknown side effects of removing and setting again the data source for the listbox, as told in the comment for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16695962/1211380

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do it to refresh the list after updating:

```
lstMeasuredValues.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid this doesn't help :/